# How to convert currency symbol to corresponding HTML entity

Tags: c#, html-entities

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&euro;"); // returns €
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("€"); // also returns €
```

How can I convert € (or any other currency symbol) to corresponding html entity.

In this example `€ => &euro;`

I'm using .Net 4.6.1

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understood what you want to achieve here. Do you want to convert the symbol back into the html entity (such as &euro in this case)?

Comment: @degant, Yes the question is in the title :)  I'm trying to find a function ConvertEveryCharacterToHtmlEntityCounterPart()

Comment: Why not let your HTML renderer do that if the document encoding doesn't support the character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HtmlEncode` only looks for a few special characters and replaces them with hard-coded values, and additionally a few more high ASCII characters (160 - 255) as described [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebUtility.cs,117). The only way to encode into entity names is by specifying them manually. I gave it a shot and built a wrapper around the `System.Net.WebUtility` class while leveraging the existing Html entities dataset used by .NET to decode as well so that decoding continues to work with this solution. I've hosted it on github: [WebUtilityWrapper](https://github.com/degant/web-utility-wrapper/blob/master/WebUtilityWrapper.cs). You can use it as shown below:

```
WebUtilityWrapper.HtmlEncode("€"); // Returns &euro;
WebUtilityWrapper.HtmlEncode("Δ"); // Returns &Delta;
WebUtilityWrapper.HtmlEncode("&"); // Returns &amp;
WebUtilityWrapper.HtmlEncode("$"); // Returns $ 
WebUtilityWrapper.HtmlEncode("€¢£¥"); // Returns &euro;&cent;&pound;&yen;
```

I've tested it out by encoding and decoding back and then verifying if we get the original string for a large set of unicode characters. Sharing some more tests:

**HtmlEncode() Response using framework's HtmlEncode:** ([link](https://github.com/degant/web-utility-wrapper/blob/master/WebUtilityWrapper.cs))

```
// Alphabets
$+0123456789&lt;=&gt;ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ^`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz|~

// Unicode 162 to 254
&#162;&#163;&#164;&#165;&#166;&#167;&#168;&#169;&#170;&#172;&#174;&#175;&#176;
&#177;&#180;&#181;&#182;&#184;&#186;&#192;&#193;&#194;&#195;&#196;&#197;&#198;
&#199;&#200;&#201;&#202;&#203;&#204;&#205;&#206;&#207;&#208;&#209;&#210;&#211;
&#212;&#213;&#214;&#215;&#216;&#217;&#218;&#219;&#220;&#221;&#222;&#223;&#224;
&#225;&#226;&#227;&#228;&#229;&#230;&#231;&#232;&#233;&#234;&#235;&#236;&#237;
&#238;&#239;&#240;&#241;&#242;&#243;&#244;&#245;&#246;&#247;&#248;&#249;&#250;
&#251;&#252;&#253;&#254;

// Unicodes for Greek Alphabet
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝ

// Unicodes for 9824 - 9830
♠♣♥♦
```

**HtmlEncode() Response using WebUtilityWrapper.HtmlEncode:**

```
// Alphabets
$+0123456789&lt;=&gt;ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ^`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz|~

// Unicode 162 to 254
&cent;&pound;&curren;&yen;&brvbar;&sect;&uml;&copy;&ordf;&not;&reg;&macr;&deg;
&plusmn;&acute;&micro;&para;&cedil;&ordm;&Agrave;&Aacute;&Acirc;&Atilde;&Auml;&Aring;&AElig;
&Ccedil;&Egrave;&Eacute;&Ecirc;&Euml;&Igrave;&Iacute;&Icirc;&Iuml;&ETH;&Ntilde;&Ograve;&Oacute;
&Ocirc;&Otilde;&Ouml;&times;&Oslash;&Ugrave;&Uacute;&Ucirc;&Uuml;&Yacute;&THORN;&szlig;&agrave;
&aacute;&acirc;&atilde;&auml;&aring;&aelig;&ccedil;&egrave;&eacute;&ecirc;&euml;&igrave;&iacute;
&icirc;&iuml;&eth;&ntilde;&ograve;&oacute;&ocirc;&otilde;&ouml;&divide;&oslash;&ugrave;&uacute;
&ucirc;&uuml;&yacute;&thorn;

// Unicodes for Greek alphabet
&Alpha;&Beta;&Gamma;&Delta;&Epsilon;&Zeta;&Eta;&Theta;&Iota;&Kappa;&Lambda;&Mu;&Nu;
&Xi;&Omicron;&Pi;&Rho;&Sigma;&Tau;&Upsilon;&Phi;&Chi;&Psi;&Omega;

// Unicodes for 9824 - 9830
&spades;&clubs;&hearts;&diams;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`HtmlEncode` and `HtmlDecode` are not symmetric.

`HtmlEncode` will only encode a handful of special characters:

- `<` => `&lt;`
- `>` => `&gt;`
- `&` => `&amp;`
- `'` => `&#39;`
- `"` => `&quot;`

and for some unicode characters it will convert them to the `&#<num>;` format.

So no conversions into HtmlEntities takes place.