# How to convert greek characters to HTML characters

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I would like to be able to do this kind of operation:

```
var specialCharactersString = "αβ";
var encodedString = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(specialCharactersString);
Console.WriteLine(encodedString); // result: &alpha;&beta;
```

We work with an external database that stores data using both notations `&alpha;&beta;` and `αβ`. We want to be able to query both terms when the end-user use `αβ`.

So far, I tried:

- WebUtility.HtmlEncode
- HttpUtility.HtmlEncode
- Encoding.GetEncoding(1253)

Comment: Are you using .Net Framework or .Net Core?  You don't need both tags.

Comment: @Amy We use both.

Comment: What exactly is the issue with `&alpha;&beta;`? That should render as `αβ` in html.

Comment: We work with an external database that stores data using both notations `&alpha;&beta;` and `αβ`. We want to be able to query both terms when the end-user use `αβ`.

Comment: What is the encoding in the external database?

Comment: UTF8 encoding (pgsql).

Comment: Check this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43717647/how-to-convert-currency-symbol-to-corresponding-html-entity#answer-43724063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@claudiom248](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11918492/claudiom248), the answer was in another Stack Overflow post.

[How to convert currency symbol to corresponding HTML entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43717647/how-to-convert-currency-symbol-to-corresponding-html-entity#answer-43724063)

https://github.com/degant/web-utility-wrapper/blob/master/WebUtilityWrapper.cs

Answer (score 0):

unicode characters and html has been a problem all the time. Here is a helper I use. Hope this helps.

**Update**: The source is from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20255/Full-HTML-Character-Encoding-in-C with very minor modification.

```
specialCharactersString.HtmlEncode()

public static class TextHelpers {
    public static string HtmlEncode(this string text)
    {
        var chars = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text).ToCharArray();

        System.Text.StringBuilder result = new System.Text.StringBuilder(text.Length + (int)(text.Length * 0.1));
        foreach (char c in chars)
        {
            int ansiValue = Convert.ToInt32(c);
            if (ansiValue > 127)
                result.AppendFormat("&#{0};", ansiValue);
            else
                result.Append(c);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `&#945;&#946;` is not the desired output. https://dotnetfiddle.net/6WXua4

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [claudiom248](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11918492/claudiom248), the .NET Framework libraries cannot properly map high ASCII html entity characters.  You can certainly pull in a 3rd party library, but if you'd like to avoid the additional cost and/or if you only have a small subset of characters that you always want to handle, you can maintain a simple dictionary lookup.

```
void Main()
{
    var specialCharactersString = "αβ"; 
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var specialChar in specialCharactersString)
    {
        var valueExists = _dict.TryGetValue(specialChar, out var mappedSpecialChar);        
        if (valueExists)
        {
            sb.Append(mappedSpecialChar);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}

private Dictionary<char, string> _dict = new Dictionary<char, string>
{
    { 'α', "&alpha;" },
    { 'β', "&beta;" }
};
```

This will output `&alpha;&beta;` as expected.